# Using sed commands on an output to find an average

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

My goal is to compute the average ping times of a website over the first 10 counts, average over the second 10 counts and average over the last 10 counts and print them in one go using bash scripting. 
So far, I have come up with the following script:

```
  ping -c 30 google.com > pings.txt 
  sed 's/\=/= /g' pings.txt > formatted_op.txt
  sed -n '2, 11p' formatted_op.txt > 1.txt
  sed -n '12, 22p' formatted_op.txt > 2.txt
  sed -n '22, 32p' formatted_op.txt > 3.txt

 awk '{print $10}' 1.txt | awk '{ sum += $1 } END {print sum/10}' > 1_avg.txt
 awk '{print $10}' 2.txt | awk '{ sum += $1 } END {print sum/10}' > 2_avg.txt
 awk '{print $10}' 3.txt | awk '{ sum += $1 } END {print sum/10}' > 3_avg.txt
 cat 1_avg.txt 2_avg.txt 3_avg.txt > final_avg.txt
 cat final_avg.txt
 rm 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 1_avg.txt 2_avg.txt 3_avg.txt formatted_op.txt pings.txt
```

However, I want to be able to do this without creating any temporary files. How do I do so?
I have also tried doing it using pipes as follows:

```
  ping -c 30 google.com | sed 's/\=/= /g' | sed -n '2, 11p' | awk '{print $10}'| awk '{ sum += $1 } END {print sum/10}'
```

but this only computes the average of the first 10 pings and using ping 3 times would give different results each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can all be done with awk pretty easily. Assuming your ping output looks like this:

```
64 bytes from yyz08s09-in-f110.1e100.net (172.217.1.110): icmp_seq=27 ttl=59 time=0.636 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s09-in-f110.1e100.net (172.217.1.110): icmp_seq=28 ttl=59 time=0.638 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s09-in-f110.1e100.net (172.217.1.110): icmp_seq=29 ttl=59 time=0.658 ms
64 bytes from yyz08s09-in-f110.1e100.net (172.217.1.110): icmp_seq=30 ttl=59 time=0.666 ms
```

This will do the trick:

```
ping -c 30 google.com | \
awk '
{
    split($8,a,"=");
    if(NR > 1 && NR < 12) {
        round1+=a[2]
    } else if (NR < 22) {
        round2+=a[2]
    } else if (NR < 32) {
        round3+=a[2]
    }
}
END {
    print round1/10" "round2/10" "round3/10
}
'
```

We use the `NR` variable to check which line of output is being processed and then increment the appropriate variable. (The value is gotten by splitting the time field on the equals sign.)

Comment: You may format the awk script to span multiple lines for better readability :)

Comment: Well I wrote the answer up before going to bed, so here it is all prettied up for the morning!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make it that complicated. Do something like

```
for i in {1..10}
do
 ping -c 30 google.com | tail -n1 | 
 awk -v count="$i" -v FS="/" '{print "Count", count,"average : ",$5}'
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
Count 1 average :  78.484
Count 2 average :  74.473
Count 3 average :  76.971
Count 4 average :  78.789
Count 5 average :  103.609
Count 6 average :  105.754
Count 7 average :  98.969
Count 8 average :  99.009
Count 9 average :  86.186
Count 10 average :  86.521
```

Comment: OP wants 3 averages after one call to `ping`.

Answer (score 1):

A pure Bash solution is not possible, because Bash has no support for floating point arithmetic. You need at least `bc`.

In order to calculate an average it is not necessary to collect and store all values. You can calculate the average incrementally. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106314/60764) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106720/60764) for the mathematics or read Volume 2 of Donald Knuth's "[The Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming)". The formula as a Bash function might look like this:

```
avg ()
{
  local a=$1 # average of the values already seen in the past
  local x=$2 # new sample
  local n=$3 # sequence number

  bc -l <<<"$a + ($x - $a) / $n"
}
```

A single ping time can be collected by the following function.

```
pingtime ()
{
  ping -c1 ${host:-localhost} |
  sed -n 's/.*time=\(.*\) .*/\1/p'
}
```

With the above functions the calculation of `n` average values with `m` samples for each average can be done with two `for` loops.

```
n=3
m=10

for i in $(seq $n); do
  a=
  for j in $(seq $m); do
    t=$(pingtime)
    if [ -z "$a" ]; then
      a=$t
    else
      a=$(avg $a $t $j)
    fi
  done
  LC_NUMERIC=C printf '%2g\n' $a
done
```

In the outer loop the average `a` is first cleared. In the inner loop the ping time is measured. If the average is empty it is initialized with the first sample. Otherwise the average is calculated. And the result is reported in the outer loop.

`bc` and `printf` behave differently depending on the localization. If necessary a specific behavior can be forced by setting `LC_NUMERIC`.

If you wish you can add a `sleep 1` in front of the `ping`, to measure only one sample per second.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try my solution

```
#!/bin/bash

pings=10

for i in {1..10};
do

  ping -c ${pings} google.pl | grep -o 'time=.*' | sed 's/time=\(.*\) ms/\1/g' | awk -v iteration="$i" -v pings="$pings" '{sum+=$1+$2+$3} END {print "Iteration " iteration " Average time " sum/pings}'

done
```